# (S)CSS Flexbox Justify-Content: Flex End Not Applying

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to achieve this (my Figma mockup):
[image: figma mockup]

Where as I keep getting this in my real coding (text is dummy):
[image: real?!]

This is my (S)CSS for the page:

```css
.navbarcont {
    margin-top: 2em;
    display: flex;
    background-color: hsl(206, 97%, 13%);
    border-radius: 34px;
    width: 80vw;
    height: 3em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    

    .links {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-left: 2em;
        align-items: center;
    }

    ul {
        display: inherit;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1em;
    }

    .langcont {
        display: inherit;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

And this is my React HTML:

```html
<div className="navbarcont">
                    <div className="links">
                        <ul> {/*TODO: Remember to put icons before the a tags! (USE BOOTSTRAP ICONS!) */}
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Hello</a>
                            </li>
                            
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Hello</a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Hello</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div className="langcont">
                        <div className="langtext">
                            <p>Language Select</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I really do not know where I am going wrong, or why I cannot use `justify-content: flex-end;` on the `langcont` class.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional `justify-content` in the `navbarcontent`-class

```css
.navbarcont {
  ...
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This will add space between the two divs and should display your elements like intended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `justify-content: space-between` property on `.navbarcont`

```
.navbarcont {
  display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
...
}
```